# Why is my footer so big?

Tags: html, css

My footer is a lot bigger than what it is supposed to be (usually just the same size as the text that is inside it) and I can't figure out why, I haven't added any code to change the default size.

Here is the basic layout of the page in HTML

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>

<div class="reservations"></div>

<table style="width:100%" class="schedule"></table>

<div class="sections">
    <section class="inner"></section>
    <section class="right"></section>

    <div class="capacity">
        <table class="capacity"></table>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>Hamilton Confrence Center  ||  8711 West Lane, Hamilton  ||  (513) 555-7911</footer>
```

And this is all that is inside my footer's css

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: white;
}
```

Yet this is what the page currently looks like (have circled footer text in case it is hard to see) ..

[image]

And as you can see, the footers background color extends well above the top of the footer text. For those of you who will ask, no I have no also changed the background color of the sections above the footer to aquamarine, they are just on default e.g white.

EDIT:

adding `clear: both;` to the footer in css fixed the issue

Comment: can you create a fiddle to replicate the problem?

Comment: The error is not reproducible from the code you've posted ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yaxnnzma/)). I'm guessing there are some floats that are not being cleared, but we don't have access to the part of the code that is at fault.

Comment: Open the page in chrome. Inspect the footer. Verify that it's bounding box truly is covering the page and that it's computed styles are as expected. Inspect the rest of the page. Check computed CSS background color. If it's aquamarine check to see where that calculated value is coming from. Check other element bounding boxes, float styles, etc. You can do similar debugging in Firefox too. This should give you hints.

Comment: He's right. Try with overflow: hidden; to the big box right above the footer to clear the floats.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mqmrexgo/

Comment: just add `clear: both;` like guessed by @DavidHedlund above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: white;    }
```

To

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
}
```

Has fixed the issue

Comment: Hey @Liam-emery, nice to see your issue fixed! StackOverflow works in a Q&A style where the correct answer from someone should be accepted. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question but please accept the answer and upvote it when it helped you to find a solution, this gains them some 'Reputation' - points that reward helping others on the site

Comment: @Kimmax This answer is more helpful to others than mine is, if my answer is what you are referring to. This should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Your reservations div from your fiddle has float:right. Clear the float before the footer. Sorry to be brief, on phone.